# Keyframe animation issue with firefox (works fine in chrome) if element was once display:none

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

**First off, I'm well aware display:none can bork transition animations.**

I have a series of hidden divs (display:none;) and I'm using an onclick JS to change the class effectively giving it a display:block with a new position.

Here is the event sequence:
 - onclick changes div from display:none to display:block
 - Adds new class with absolute position
 - Keyframes to animate new positioning (slides right).

This **works fine in Chrome** but for some reason firefox is ignoring the animations.

**When I inspect it in firefox I can check/unckeck the animation CSS and it will properly animate so I know it's no an issue with my css markup, at this point it is display:block.**

Anyone have any ideas on a work-around for this?

If anyone has a solution I'll forever be in your debt.

Comment: Try to do: change to `display:block` - `setTimeout([add animation class],0)`.

Comment: Giving you an upboat for the reply. I managed to rectify the issue with an additional addClass.  Thanks for responding!